# Python force dict entries to be utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, dictionary

I spent the better part of an afternoon trying to patch dictionary objects to be utf-8 encoded in lieu of unicode. I am trying to find the fastest and best performing way to extend a dictionary object and ensure that it's entries, keys and values are both utf-8.

Here is what I have come up with, it does the job but I'm wondering what improvements could be made.

```
class UTF8Dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        d = _decode_dict(d)
        super(UTF8Dict,self).__init__(d)
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        if isinstance(key,unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(value,unicode):
            value = value.encode('utf-8')
        return super(UTF8Dict,self).__setitem__(key,value)

def _decode_list(data):
    rv = []
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, unicode):
            item = item.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            item = _decode_list(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            item = _decode_dict(item)
        rv.append(item)
    return rv

def _decode_dict(data):
    rv = {}
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(key, unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            value = value.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            value = _decode_list(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = _decode_dict(value)
        rv[key] = value
    return rv
```

Suggestions that improve any of the following would be very helpful:

- Performance
- Cover more edge-cases
- Error handling

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just store your keys/values as unicode objects, then encode as needed. The most you need in your extension is an isinstance check which raises an exception if it fails.

Comment: Best practice is to encode and decode at the input and output edges of your code (so decode as soon as you receive, encode as late as possible when sending out), and maintain as unicode within.

Comment: Why force anything? Just make a dictionary and only add keys/values with the correct encoding. Trying to force types and encodings isn't Pythonic.

Comment: Also, this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't have access to the layer that's adding or manipulating the objects, nor do I have access to the layer that's reading from the object, I have to make sure that whomever reads from this gets ONLY utf8 no matter what.

Comment: You won't be able to ensure that there's only utf8 "no matter what" -- e.g., there's no way to prevent a user from directly calling `dict.setitem` on your subclass instance to add a unicode string.

Comment: Then maybe writing a whole new object from scratch would be better way to enforce compliance.  This is not my idea nor my plan but it's what is asked.

Comment: @lukecampbell Another option might be to override the various read methods (`getitem`, etc) to ensure that they encode any unicode strings before returning them.  This would not be trivial, though -- e.g., handling `__iter__` and `viewitems` correctly wouldn't be simple.

Comment: “UTF-8 instead of Unicode”.  Say what?

Comment: @tchrist: Python has distinct types for "str" (byte strings) and "unicode" (a sequence of unicode codepoints). UTF-8 is one particular encoding for Unicode; it specifies what the bytes in the byte string should be. Try it yourself in a Python interpreter: `s = u'résumé'; s; t = s.encode('utf8'); t;`. The OP wants byte strings (encoded in UTF-8), not Unicode strings (which are agnostic to encoding, whether UTF-8 or UTF-16 or whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments that say that this may be misguided.  That said, here are some holes in your current scheme:

1. `d.setdefault` can be used to add unicode objects to your dict:

   ```
   >>> d = UTF8Dict()
   >>> d.setdefault(u'x', u'y')
   ```
2. `d.update` can be used to add unicode objects to your dict:

   ```
   >>> d = UTF8Dict()
   >>> d.update({u'x': u'y'})
   ```
3. the list values contained in a dict could be modified to include unicode objects, using any standard list operations.  E.g.:

   ```
   >>> d = UTF8Dict(x=[])
   >>> d['x'].append(u'x')
   ```

*Why* do you want to ensure that your data structure contains only utf-8 strings?

Comment: _I_ don't.  The endpoint that this connects to only handles utf-8.  Their exact code is this `if type(s) is str: hate_my_life()` so that's why I'm patching all this.  I asked them to change it to `isinstance(s,basestring)` but "we aren't ready for unicode yet"  Haven't quite figured out that one yet.

Comment: @lukecampbell Would it be practical to write a function that takes a dict as its input, walks the dict (and any substructures you care about), and encodes any unicode strings?  You could then call this function just before using the external "endpoint" code that requires utf-8 in its input dicts.

Comment: I went that route originally, hence the two functions under the object definition, but the underlying endpoints which extend from dict are now going to extend this object which forces utf-8 compliance.  I can't enforce the policy that clients use utf-8 when dealing with dicts.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you monkey-patch the evil module that's doing `if type(s) is str`?  E.g., inject a `type` function into its namespace that looks something like: `if isinstance(s,basestring): return str; else: return __builtins__.type(s)`?  Not exactly clean, I admit. :)

Comment: I actually just flat out changed it to `isinstance(s,basestring)` but then got an email basically saying "dont touch that its not in your domain"  Long email chain followed for me trying to push unicode support which IS NOT HARD in Python.